# Python Dictionary: Replace values based on key occurrence in other values

Tags: python, dictionary

My question might involve comprehension if I'm not mistaken.
So I have a dictionary as:

```
data = {
 1: [2, 4], 
 2: [3], 
 3: [1, 2, 6], 
 4: [1, 3, 6], 
 6: [3, 4]
}
```

I wish to rearrange the dictionary values (not keys) such that with every occurrence of a "key" in any of the other values, the current key's values should now contain the "key" in who's value it originally occurred.
For example the dictionary should now look like this:

```
new_data = {
 1: [3, 4], 
 2: [1, 3], 
 3: [2, 4, 6], 
 4: [1, 6], 
 6: [3, 4]
}
```

I know for sure that I must use another empty dictionary to solve this, and I must use looping. I have a starting point, but it's not efficient:

```
for pk,pv in zip(data.keys(), data.values()):
    #print(pk,pv)
    for pvs in pv:
        #print(pvs)
        if pk == pvs:
            new_data.setdefault(pk, [])
            new_data[pk].append(pvs)

print(new_data)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)
(Using Ubuntu 14.04 32-Bit VM and Python 2.7)

Comment: Just curious what your reasoning for "it's not efficient" is.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking, at least to me..

Comment: your solution works or does not work? what do you mean with "not efficient"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that the code doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps this is not the most efficient way to do this, but I would argue it's one of the nicest to read :).

One thing I should say before, if it's possible to change the initial dictionary values to `set` instead of `list`, that could result in some performance gains since `set` membership checks can be faster than `lists`s.

Here goes:

```
def present_in(k, d):
    return {idx for idx in d if k in d[idx]}

new_data = {k: present_in(k, data) for k in data}
```

Basically the `present_in` function creates a set of values corresponding to keys where `k` is present as a member. We simply then use this to create the `new_data` dictionary using a dictionary comprehension. Note again the values of this dictionary is a set, instead of a list. You can easily wrap them in `list()` if you do need lists.

EDIT:

If you would like `new_data` to have keys that may be missing as keys in `data` but present as one of the values, you can change the code to create a set of all possible keys first:

```
all_keys = {v for vs in data.values() for v in vs}

def present_in(k, d):
    return {idx for idx in d if k in d[idx]}

new_data = {k: present_in(k, data) for k in all_keys}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @bow . Out of curiosity, let's say that key `2` and its values are missing/no longer present in the `data` dictionary and I still want to print it in the `new_data` dictionary based on it's occurrence in the other values in `data` dictionary. How do I modify the `def`?

Comment: Basically, what I'm trying to say is that the keys are like `nodes` `1,2,3,4,5` in a network. In `data` these `nodes` send messages to other `nodes` which are the `values`. And in `new_data` the keys are the receivers of these messages from other nodes. So, even if a node hasn't sent a message, it should still receive a message from the others. I hope this analogy helps in a bit of clarification :)

Comment: Hmm..in that case, you'd need to replace the `for k in d` expression with something else. I would first have a set storing all the nodes: `nodes = {k for vs in data.values() for v in vs}` and then `for k in d` becomes `for k in nodes`. That is a set comprehension that creates a set of all possible nodes present as values in `data`.

Comment: If it's possible, could you please update the same in your answer? I tried what you suggested but it's not working for me

Answer (score 1):

```
{k:[i for i,j in data.items() if k in j] for k,_ in data.items()}
#Output:
#{1: [3, 4], 2: [1, 3], 3: [2, 4, 6], 4: [1, 6], 6: [3, 4]}
```

The below part essentially checks if the key(k from outer dict) is present in any of the values in dict, if present, it'll get the corresponding key into the list

```
[i for i,j in data.items() if k in j]
```

Comment: I deleted my answer, since it was essentially the same as yours (20sec later), but please do add some explanation and details.